# Custom Django admin action, remove entries related by ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models:

```
A(models.Model):
    field = models.IntegerField()

B(models.Model):
    f = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

And in admin panel I have custom action, which clears(resets) some info in `Model A`:

```
def clear_something(modeladmin, request, queryset):
     queryset.update(field=0)
```

How could I make custom action `clear_something` delete all related `Model B` entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming queryset is a set of A's, you should be able to loop over them and delete the 'b_set' (reverse FK lookup) of each, like so:

```
def clear_something(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(field=0)
    for a in queryset:
        a.b_set.all().delete()
```

Alternatively, use B's model manager:

```
def clear_something(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(field=0)
    for a in queryset:
        B.objects.filter(f=a).delete()
```